# libcrypto.a symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Tags: xcode

xcode 6.3 beta

I'm using libcrypto.a in my project.

My app can compile and run on my ipod touch5 (armv7).

But when I try to run my app on a iphone5 simulator, I'm getting the error:

```
  "_closedir$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_DIR_end in libcrypto.a(o_dir.o)

  "_fputs$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _write_string in libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o)
      _read_string in libcrypto.a(ui_openssl.o)

  "_opendir$INODE64$UNIX2003", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_DIR_read in libcrypto.a(o_dir.o)

  "_readdir$INODE64", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_DIR_read in libcrypto.a(o_dir.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
```

Then I checked what architectures the libcrypto.a I'm using support using the command:

```
lipo -info libcrypto.a
```

and get the result:

```
Architectures in the fat file: libcrypto.a are: i386 armv7 armv7s arm64
```

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 6):

create new m file anywhere.
and define all missing function here:

```js
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fnmatch.h>

FILE *fopen$UNIX2003( const char *filename, const char *mode )
{
    return fopen(filename, mode);
}

int fputs$UNIX2003(const char *res1, FILE *res2){
    return fputs(res1,res2);
}

int nanosleep$UNIX2003(int val){
    return usleep(val);
}

char* strerror$UNIX2003(int errornum){
    return strerror(errornum);
}

double strtod$UNIX2003(const char *nptr, char **endptr){
    return strtod(nptr, endptr);
}

size_t fwrite$UNIX2003( const void *a, size_t b, size_t c, FILE *d )
{
    return fwrite(a, b, c, d);
}

DIR * opendir$INODE64( char * dirName )
{
    return opendir( dirName );
}

struct dirent * readdir$INODE64( DIR * dir )
{
    return readdir( dir );
}
```