# symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 in libssl.a when building it for pjsip

Tags: ios, openssl, pjsip

I am trying to build PJSIP library for IOS simulator with openssl support.
I followed the instructions mentioned in this link
https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone
PJSIP website directs to Openssl wiki installation and instructions page for guidance.

so to build openssl for my iPhone simulator these were the commands which i gave.

```
export CC="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/../../../Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang"
KERNEL_BITS=64  ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc no-shared no-dso no-hw no-engine --prefix=$HOME/ssl
make depend
make
make install_sw
```

After this i am able to see that openssl seems to build without any errors or warnings in terminal in the folder path i mentioned in command.
so to double check ,i use this command on the **libssl.a** file

```
lipo -info libssl.a 
Non-fat file: libssl.a is architecture: x86_64
```

I seem to be very happy after seeing that lib file is built successfully.

Now next step is link this with pjsip library build.
I follow the steps mentioned in pjsip website.
These are the commands which i fed into my terminal

```
export DEVPATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer
    ARCH="-arch x86_64" CFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" LDFLAGS="-O2 -m64 -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0" ./configure-iphone  --with-ssl=/Users/nexgetech01/ssl 
    make dep && make
```

As mentioned in pjsip website,i am able to see that my newly build openssl library has been successfully linked and tested by pjsip commands in terminal

```
checking for OpenSSL installations..
Using SSL prefix... /Users/nexgetech01/ssl
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... no
aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: accepted by the compiler, rejected by the preprocessor!
aconfigure: WARNING: openssl/ssl.h: proceeding with the compiler's result
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for ERR_load_BIO_strings in -lcrypto... yes
checking for SSL_CTX_new in -lssl... yes
OpenSSL library found, SSL support enabled
```

So everything seems too good and continue that process.But end of that compilation im stuck with this errors

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_opendir$INODE64", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_DIR_read in libcrypto.a(o_dir.o)
  "_readdir$INODE64", referenced from:
      _OPENSSL_DIR_read in libcrypto.a(o_dir.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

So to make sure that,i used the following command on terminal on my **libcrypto.a**

```
    nm -A libcrypto.a |grep OPENSSL_DIR_rea
libcrypto.a:o_dir.o: 0000000000000000 T _OPENSSL_DIR_read
```

i can find that as undefined in my libcrypto.a.i dont know what i am missing while building the openssl library??Im stuck with building this openssl library for a week.Please direct me so i can sort this out.

Comment: check your architecture  x86_64   support in device only.

Comment: bro nan simulator ku than bro build pannrean

Comment: for some reasons the libssl.a which i build is not having the above mentioned symbols.so i am not able to link it with pjsip

Comment: ASYNC_get_current_job and the other ASYNC functions are all defined in libcrypto not libssl. libssl just uses them. Looks like it might not be picking up the right version of libcrypto for some reason?

Comment: @MattCaswell ok mate let me check libcrypto too

Comment: @MattCaswell after checking i found that libcrypto version were different in my lib folders so again i built for architecture now stuck with two errors

Comment: @MattCaswell can you guide me??

Comment: So now the missing symbols are opendir and readdir - which are referenced from libcrypto. These are defined in libc so they should always be there. Not sure why they're not found for you. Perhaps some mix-up in 32-bit libc vs 64-bit libc?

Comment: @MattCaswell mate you seem to know in and outs of openssl.so how can i check libc??maybe u r right bcuz of 64bit i maybe missing something

Comment: Not sure I can help...seems to be something specific to simulating on an iphone. A google search turns up a number of similar errors all relating to iphone. There's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29390112/libcrypto-a-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-i386, but its not accepted so don't know if it worked.

Comment: @MattCaswell okay mate thanks let me give a try